# swift uitableview and tablecell click to start song

Tags: ios, mysql, swift, uitableview, tablecell

Ok so i am pretty new to swift, i have tried a lot and it starting to come together. So now i have a tablecell in tableview with a list of songs coming from mysql done with json. The database (mysql) also holds the url to the music file and the thumbnail. I would like to do the following thing with this.

Whenever i click an track in the tableview to update the track url and the thumb url and everythings else to reflect to the song that is playing/selected.

I know i have to do it somewhere in this

```
 func tableView(tableView:UITableView, didSelectRowIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

}
```

but i have no idea how to use the reload function to do it on this page I have read so many page on here but they are all for people with more basic knowledge than i have.

My full code is below. I hope some one can teach me how to do this. I will be reusing this kind of function many times over.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class RightSideViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var playerView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pauseButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!

    var artistname:Array< String > = Array < String >()
    var trackname:Array< String > = Array < String >()

    var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?
    var player:AVPlayer?
    var musicFile = "http://xxxx"



    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        var musicUrl = NSURL(string: musicFile)
        playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: musicUrl!)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem!)

        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player!)
        playerLayer.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        playButton.addTarget(self, action: "playButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        get_data_from_url("http://xxxxxx.php")

    }


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "finishedPlaying:", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: playerItem)
    }


    func playButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject){
        if player?.rate == 0
        {
            player!.play()
            playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        } else {
            player!.pause()
            playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    func finishedPlaying(myNotification:NSNotification){
        playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        let stopedPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem = myNotification.object as! AVPlayerItem
        stopedPlayerItem.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
    }


     func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return artistname.count
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("playerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!MusicTableViewCell
        cell.artistLabel?.text = artistname[indexPath.row]
        cell.trackName?.text = trackname[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView:UITableView, didSelectRowIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    }

    func get_data_from_url(url:String)
    {
        let httpMethod = "GET"
        let timeout = 15
        let url = NSURL(string: url)
        let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!,
            cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
            timeoutInterval: 15.0)
        let queue = NSOperationQueue()
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(
            urlRequest,
            queue: queue,
            completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,
                data: NSData!,
                error: NSError!) in
                if data.length > 0 && error == nil{
                    let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
                    self.extract_json(json!)
                }else if data.length == 0 && error == nil{
                    println("Nothing was downloaded")
                } else if error != nil{
                    println("Error happened = \(error)")
                }
            }
        )
    }


    func extract_json(data:NSString)
    {
        var parseError: NSError?
        let jsonData:NSData = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
        let json: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &parseError)
        if (parseError == nil)
        {
            if let countries_list = json as? NSArray
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < countries_list.count ; i++ )
                {
                    if let country_obj = countries_list[i] as? NSDictionary
                    {
                        if let track_names = country_obj["track_name"] as? String
                        {
                            if let dj_names = country_obj["artist"] as? String
                            {
                                artistname.append(dj_names)
                                trackname.append(track_names)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        do_table_refresh();
    }


    func do_table_refresh()
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.playerView.reloadData()
            return
        })
    }
}
```

I really appreciate the help. thanks

Comment: We are all here to help:) tell us more clearly what exactly you want to do when a user taps on the cell? I may not have an answer but others would, so please elaborate as much as you can.

Comment: it is pretty simple, when they click a cell, then the thumb and the url that the cell  holds (you wont see it but it is all being all pulled from the mysql) should update the avplayer and also the labels on the uiviewcontroller that holds the tabelcell. It like spotify, you click a sogn and it starts playing and all info is being updated. I hope clarifies things a little.

Comment: Do you parse the URL and the thumb anywhere from the JSON, and store it somewhere? I would recommend to do that first (just like you have stored artistname etc.) if your are not doing it, because the table view will have no idea where to get the data from. Also, I would recommend create one array only and store objects for each song in it (dictionary perhaps, just like country_obj?), that way it would be easier to access it anywhere in your code. If you can paste a sample node of your JSON, that could also help others in solving your problem.

Comment: the code you see here is all the code i have. I thought i was pretty far on my way :) I have the artist name and all stored in he string. The thing i need is to update them with the value when i click on a tablecell. So lick on the option in the table sell and the variables who make the new song get updated and start playing or i can click start play.

Comment: You are close buddy, so don't worry. Look for these things inside your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method: the method needs to have the URL for the music player to play, the thumbnail, the artist name and the track name (you have this), and the instance to the player in order to play and update. Think of a way to get these things to inside that method and you should be even closer.